# Guardar una instancia sin clave principal

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Estoy intentando realizar un actualizar y me arroja este error:

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You attempted to save an
> instance with no primary key, this is not allowed since it would
> result in a global update"

¿Me pueden ayudar por favor? Gracias

Este es el código:

```
export async function updatefinca(req, res) {
try {
    const { id_finca } = req.params;
    const { id_ganadero, id_ubicacion, nombre_finca, fecha_registro_finca } = req.body;

    const Fincas = await finca.findAll({
        attributes: ['id_finca', 'id_ganadero', 'id_ubicacion', 'nombre_finca', 'descripcion'],
        where: {

            id_finca

        }
    });
    if (Fincas.length > 0) {
        Fincas.forEach(async finca => {
            await finca.update({
                id_ganadero,
                id_ubicacion,
                nombre_finca,
                fecha_registro_finca
            });
        })
    }
    return res.json({
        message: 'finca actualizada correctamente',
        data: Fincas
    })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(id_finca);
    res.status(500).json({
        message: 'error de al actualizar',
        data: {}
    })

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no se entiende. Si has usado un traductor para el mensaje de error, el mismo no es muy eficiente. Sería aconsejable en este caso que también coloques el mesaje de error original (además de la traducción). Por otro lado, el código debe ir en formato texto y no como imagen. Saludos

Comment: gracias ya lo organice